Trying to deposit ETH to my contract with Chainlink Functions. Getting gas estimation errors
We were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail
Keep getting this error when I am trying to deposit to my contract that is using Chainlink Functions to call to an API to fetch prices.
This is my contract :
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.25;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/dev/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/dev/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";
import {MintableToken} from "../src/MintableToken.sol";
import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Synthetic is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal dataFeed;

    // State variables to store the last request ID, response, and error
    bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
    bytes public s_lastResponse;
    bytes public s_lastError;
    uint64 subscriptionId;
    address public fetchData = address(this);
    // Custom error type
    error UnexpectedRequestID(bytes32 requestId);

    // Event to log responses
    event Response(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        string character,
        bytes response,
        bytes err
    );

    // event TokensMinted(address indexed minter, uint256 totalMintedTokens);
    event TokensMinted(address indexed user, uint256 amount, address token);

    address router = 0xC22a79eBA640940ABB6dF0f7982cc119578E11De;

    // JavaScript source code
    string source =
        "const ticker = args[0];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "url: `https://chainlink-wine.vercel.app/api/alpha/${ticker}`"
        "});"
        "if (apiResponse.error) {"
        "throw Error('Request failed');"
        "}"
        "const { data } = apiResponse;"
        "const dataMultiplied = data * 100;"
        "return Functions.encodeUint256(dataMultiplied);";

    //Callback gas limit
    uint32 gasLimit = 300000;

    bytes32 donID =
        0x66756e2d706f6c79676f6e2d616d6f792d310000000000000000000000000000;

    // State variable to store the returned character information
    uint256 public price;

    mapping(address => uint256) public depositedAmount;
    mapping(address => MintableToken) public syntheticTokens;
    mapping(address => address[]) public walletToContractAddresses;
    // uint256 public constant DEPOSIT_AMOUNT = 1 ether;
    uint256 public lastStockPrice;
    uint256 constant OVER_COLLATERALIZATION_RATIO = 2; // 200% over-collateral

    constructor(
        uint64 _subId
    ) FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        subscriptionId = _subId;
        dataFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            0xF0d50568e3A7e8259E16663972b11910F89BD8e7
        );
    }

    function getChainlinkDataFeedLatestAnswer() public view returns (int256) {
        // prettier-ignore
        (
            /* uint80 roundID */,
            int answer,
            /*uint startedAt*/,
            /*uint timeStamp*/,
            /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
        ) = dataFeed.latestRoundData();
        return answer;
    }

    function sendRequest(
        string[] calldata args
    ) internal returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source); // Initialize the request with JS code
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args); // Set the arguments for the request

        // Send the request and store the request ID
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionId,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId); // Check if request IDs match
        }

        s_lastResponse = response;
        price = convertBytesToUint(response);
        s_lastError = err;

        // Emit an event to log the response
        // emit Response(requestId, price, s_lastResponse, s_lastError);
    }

    function convertBytesToUint(
        bytes memory response
    ) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newprice = abi.decode(response, (uint256));
        return newprice;
    }

    function bytesToUint(bytes32 _bytes) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return uint256(_bytes);
    }

    uint256 public depositValue;

    function depositAndMint(
        // uint256 amountToMint,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string[] calldata _stock
    ) external payable {
        //fetch stock price
        bytes32 stockPriceBytes32 = sendRequest(_stock);
        uint256 stockPrice = bytesToUint(stockPriceBytes32);
        lastStockPrice = stockPrice;

        //fetch the price of eth in usd???? using chainlink price feeds
        int256 ethPriceInUsd = getChainlinkDataFeedLatestAnswer();
        require(msg.value > 0, "Insufficient deposit amount");
        depositedAmount[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        uint256 depositValueInUsd = (uint256(ethPriceInUsd) * msg.value) / 1e18;
        depositValue = depositValueInUsd;
        // Calculate the maximum mintable token value based on the over-collateralization ratio
        uint256 maxMintableTokenValueInUsd = depositValueInUsd /
            OVER_COLLATERALIZATION_RATIO;
        // Calculate the number of tokens to mint based on the stock price
        uint256 tokensToMint = maxMintableTokenValueInUsd / uint256(stockPrice);

        MintableToken newToken = new MintableToken(
            _name,
            _symbol,
            tokensToMint
        );
        syntheticTokens[msg.sender] = newToken;
        newToken.mint(msg.sender, tokensToMint);

        //store minted tokens to address mapping
        walletToContractAddresses[msg.sender].push(address(newToken));
        //emit an event for total minted tokens to address
        emit TokensMinted(msg.sender, tokensToMint, address(newToken));
    }

    // function redeemAndBurn(uint256 amountToBurn) external {
    //     require(
    //         syntheticTokens[msg.sender].balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amountToBurn,
    //         "Insufficient token balance"
    //     );
    //     syntheticTokens[msg.sender].burn(msg.sender, amountToBurn);
    //     uint256 redeemAmount = (amountToBurn * DEPOSIT_AMOUNT) /
    //         syntheticTokens[msg.sender].totalSupply();
    //     depositedAmount[msg.sender] -= redeemAmount;
    //     payable(msg.sender).transfer(redeemAmount);
    // }
}


I would really appreciate anyone's help

Chainlink Price Feed data has 8 decimals, so you have to convert it into 18 decimals by multiplying with 1e10, before proceeding with your calculation of depositValueInUsd.
int256 ethPriceInUsd = getChainlinkDataFeedLatestAnswer() * 1e10; // To get ETH/USD rate in 18 digits


Thank you so much, I will try if this works and let you know
